# PHP OOP - How do I define a CONST with a Variable or Function Output?

Tags: php, oop, constants

My specific case is that I am trying to define a path into a constant.  Right now I hard code as such:

```
class Cache
{
   const PATH_TO_CACHE = '/home/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/cache/';
```

But I need the define to be portable.  So the path can be detected, put in a variable, then put in the class. Essentially, what I want to accomplish is:

```
$somepath = {code to get path};

class Cache 
{
const PATH_TO_CACHE = $somepath;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to use dependency injection for this. For example:

```
class Cache {

  private $path_to_cache;

  function __construct($cache_path) {
    $this->path_to_cache = $cache_path;
  } 

}
```

Then you can use a defined setting:

```
$cache = new Cache($GLOBALS['config']['cache_path']);
$cache = new Cache($_SERVER['cache_path']);
$cache = new Cache($some_other_way_to_get_cache_path);
```

etc.

You can also easily change the path when developing / debugging:

```
$cache = new Cache('path/to/folder/that/is/being/problematic');
```

Comment: DI FTW.  Best practice here, keeping it SOLID. This is the correct answer and should be marked as so. +1

Comment: Oops doesn't work.  I receive:  Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'PATH_TO_CACHE'

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a workaround for this:

```
class Cache 
{
    const PATH_TO_CACHE = 'whateverYouWantToNameIt';

    private $_config = array(
        self::PATH_TO_CACHE => ''
    );

    public __construct() {
        $somePath = 'construct this path by your rules';
        $this->_config[self::PATH_TO_CACHE] = $somepath;
    }

    public function getConfig($configKey)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($configKey, $this->_config)) {
            return $this->_config[$configKey];
        }
    }
}
```

Basically you create an array with a key as a constant and this way you can always get that value like so:

```
$cacheObj = new Cache();
$somePath = $cacheObj->getConfig(Cache::PATH_TO_CACHE);
```

My guess is that you intend to force the users of the class to access that path via a constant value.
However this method shouldn't be used if you only have one constant, it beats the purpose of an array.